# Informix IDS ontape restore with rename

Tags: informix

I have two databases on one machine.  The directories holding the chunks for each are almost identical, /dev/online/live and /dev/online/test.

So I read the documentation, and constructed a shell script which ends with:

```
ontape -r -rename -f ./rename_chunks.txt
```

rename_chunks.txt contains:

```
/dev/online/live/root_dbs       8       /dev/online/dev/root_dbs        8
/dev/online/live/database_dbs   16      /dev/online/dev/database_dbs    16
/dev/online/live/data_dbs       16      /dev/online/dev/data_dbs        16
/dev/online/live/index_dbs      16      /dev/online/dev/index_dbs       16
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       16      /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        16
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       500016  /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        500016
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       1000016 /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        1000016
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       1500016 /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        1500016
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       2000016 /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        2000016
/dev/online/live/temp_dbs       2500016 /dev/online/dev/temp_dbs        2500016
/dev/online/live/db1_dbs        16      /dev/online/dev/db1_dbs 16
/dev/online/live/db1_dbs        15000008        /dev/online/dev/db1_dbs 15000008
```

I also checked that the ROOT parameters in the two ONCONFIG files are identical, which they are:

```
[testhse2][v6live][inhv6] Dev > grep ROOT *v6live *v6test | grep -v ':#'
onconfig.v6live:ROOTNAME        rootdbs
onconfig.v6live:ROOTPATH /dev/online/live/root_dbs
onconfig.v6live:ROOTOFFSET      16
onconfig.v6live:ROOTSIZE        2000000
onconfig.v6test:ROOTNAME        rootdbs
onconfig.v6test:ROOTPATH /dev/online/dev/root_dbs
onconfig.v6test:ROOTOFFSET      16
onconfig.v6test:ROOTSIZE        2000000
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Continue restore? (y/n)y
Do you want to back up the logs? (y/n)n
Physical restore failed - ONCONFIG ROOTPATH:ROOTOFFSET **'/dev/online/dev/root_dbs:16' differs from archive '/dev/online/live/root_dbs:16'**
Correct ONCONFIG before restoring this archive.
```

Whilst I can see a disconnect betweeh the offset fron onstat -d and the ONCONFIG, this has never stopped us restoring from the real live machine so I'm not sure it should now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your onconfig files show an offset for the rootdbs of 16 kB whereas the chunk rename file is showing 8 - presumably 8 pages for a 2k page size instance. The offsets in the chunk rename file also need to be in kB as mentioned in the documentation for ontape utility syntax (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/ids_bar_324.htm). Try changing all the offset values in the rename file to be in kB.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the pages / kbytes trap, I need to revise my script to take account of that.

However I would have thought there are times when the renaming restore HAS to have different offsets?

Comment: OK Penny has dropped (clang!), the offsets for the source chunks needs to match what is in the ontape, whereas the ones for the target chunks could well be different.  

Thanks, will have a go at restoring it tomorrow morning.  I hate the kbytes / pages thing.  Really hate it!